# How would you write 2^2(1 + square root of 2) in java?

Tags: java, math, formula

I am trying to attempt to create a code block which calculates the area of a floor space with user input (in this case my scanner input variable is s), but the area isn't calculating properly. What would be the correct way to write out the formula? Below is what I currently have.

```
double sForArea = s * 2;
double floorArea = (Math.pow(sForArea, 2)*(1 + Math.sqrt(2)));
```

Comment: What is the shape of the floor?  What shape does `2^2(1 + square root of 2)` represent?  What is `s`?

Comment: ```2*Math.pow(s, 2*(1+Math.sqrt(2))```

Comment: 2s² would be `2*Math.pow(s, 2)`, not `Math.pow(s*2, 2)`

Comment: I think you have some ambiguity in your formula writing.  s^2(a), does this means (s^2)*a or (s^2)*a?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you've translated that formula correctly.

I'd guess it should look like this:

```
// assume s is some characteristic length
double floorArea = 2.0*s*s*(1.0 + Math.sqrt(2.0)));
```

Note: There's no need for `Math.pow()` here.  Squaring a number just means multiplying it by itself.

Others have noted that you have some ambiguity in your written formula.  It's not clear what the term in parentheses is supposed to be multiplying.  I wrote it in the way that makes most sense.  It keeps the units as length squared, as it must be for area.